# Efficient way to use to loop through the list in Java

Tags: java, loops

I have a function logic that will fail the process if there are price dtos that have null item & current price properties.

I was wondering if there's a more efficient or cleaner way to do this in Java. In streams or any other.

Here is my current code:

```
List<PriceDto> priceDtoList = thisIsAClass.getPriceDtos();

 for (PriceDto priceDto: priceDtoList) {
        if (priceDto.getItem() == null && priceDto.getCurrentPrice() == null) 
         {
            thisIsAnotherClass.failTheProcess();
            break;
        }
    }

  thisIsAnotherClass.anotherProcess();
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: another way is using java Stream , findFirst() method

Comment: Why would you *continue* the process after *failing* it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The more common way in newer version Java would be to use `findFirst` or `findAny`.

For example,

```
List<PriceDto> priceDtoList = thisIsAClass.getPriceDtos();

Optional<PriceDto> result = list
            .stream()
            .filter(dto -> dto.getItem() ==null && dto.getCurrentPrice() == null)
            .findAny();


if(result.isPresent()) {
     thisIsAnotherClass.failTheProcess();
}

  thisIsAnotherClass.continueTheProcess();
```

If you have a lot of data in the list you could also look at adding a `.parallel()` call to the stream to improve overall performance of the search.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I checked the `Stream`  and also found that `anyMatch` would do. I'm not sure if that's better to use or just use `findAny`? Not really a lot of data. Maybe a max of 5?

Comment: If you don't need the object that matched then `anyMatch` is better for your case because it will short circuit but filter is going to process the whole stream. If you need access to the object that matched then use the find cases.